# Exception: Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: Textbox

Tags: vb.net, winforms, exception

I got this exception when I debuging in Visual Studio and don't have any idea to fix it. Please help. I used tooltip on the form, that's my guess of the cause.

I just leave it there and let it run. The exception just happens.

```
Exceptions Details:
    System.ObjectDisposedException occurred
      HResult=-2146232798
      Message=Cannot access a disposed object.
    Object name: 'TextBox'.
      ObjectName=TextBox
      Source=System.Windows.Forms
      StackTrace:
           at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateHandle()
      InnerException:
```

I think I have the same problem with this post. 
[C# WinForms: ToolTip, cannot access to a disposed object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13461972/c-sharp-winforms-tooltip-cannot-access-to-a-disposed-object)

But I still don't know how to fix it. Thanks.

**Edit:**

```
Dim frmFilterSelection As New FilterBoxSelection
  With frmFilterSelection
     .Owner = Me
     .ShowDialog()                              **HERE IS The Exception Location**
     If .DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
         If Not .SelectedFilter Is Nothing Then
            Dim newProjectItem As New cProjectItem
            ......
```

I waited 2 hours to see this exception. It is very hard to reproduce it.

**Edit2:**
After I click "Continue". The exception was caught by outer Try Catch. The exception info are in details:

```
System.ObjectDisposedException was caught
HResult=-2146232798
Message=Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'TextBox'.
ObjectName=TextBox
Source=System.Windows.Forms
StackTrace:
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateHandle()
   at System.Windows.Forms.TextBoxBase.CreateHandle()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.get_Handle()
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip.Hide(IWin32Window win)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip.TimerHandler(Object source, EventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Timer.OnTick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Timer.TimerNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.RunDialog(Form form)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog(IWin32Window owner)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog()
   at Fansil.ProjectInfoForm.CreateNewFilterBox(String inType, Boolean isTransferedData) in C:\VAW-PROJECTS\Modified\SPS8-VS2012-2014-11-17 - TEST VERSION\Fansil 6.0\ProjectInfoForm.vb:line 15030
   at Fansil.ProjectInfoForm.cbnFBH_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\VAW-PROJECTS\Modified\SPS8-VS2012-2014-11-17 - TEST VERSION\Fansil 6.0\ProjectInfoForm.vb:line 14785
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.RaiseEvent(Object key, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.HandleClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.HandleMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.FireEventInteractive(EventArgs e, ToolStripItemEventType met)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.FireEvent(EventArgs e, ToolStripItemEventType met)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mea)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDown.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mea)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDown.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.RunDialog(Form form)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog(IWin32Window owner)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog()
   at VAWPrice.frmStartUpInternal.frmStartUpInternal_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\VAW-PROJECTS\Published\SPS8-VS2012-2014-11-17 - TEST VERSION\FansilMaintenance\frmStartUpInternal.vb:line 70
InnerException:
```

Comment: Can you show the code where the exception occurs?

Comment: Set a breakpoint on frmFilterSelection and press F10 once. Hover over frmFilterSelection and make sure its nothing. Also what is FilterBoxSelection?